# Objective C, Syncronized

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

```
 @Syncronized(nodeMode.neighborNodeListeners) //neighborNodeListeners is NSMutalble array
```

Lets say I set neighborNodeListeners as

```
 @property(retain) NSMutableArray *neighborNodeListeners
```

Do I still need the Syncronized block? "neighborNodeListeners" will be accessed by multiple threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not needed. Default property is `atomic`.